# import complex data structure in hive with custom separators

Tags: arrays, hadoop, separator

I have a huge dataset with the following structure

fieldA,fieldB,fieldC;fieldD|fieldE,FieldF;fieldG|fieldH,FieldI ...

where:

fieldA,fieldB and fieldC are strings that should be imported into separate columns

fieldD|fieldE,FieldF;fieldG|fieldH,FieldI is an array (elements separated by semicolon) of maps (elements separated by |) of arrays (elements separated by comma, e.g. fieldE,FieldF)

My problem is that the initial array is separated from the fieldA,fieldB,fieldC with a semicolon. My question is how do I set the separators correctly when I create a table.

This one does not recognize an array - although I provide a semicolon as a field separator

```
CREATE TABLE string_array(
    first_part STRING # this would be to store fieldA,fieldB,fieldC
   ,second_part ARRAY<STRING> # this would be to store fieldD|fieldE,FieldF;fieldG|fieldH,FieldI and split it by semicolon
       )
ROW FORMAT DELIMITED
    FIELDS TERMINATED BY '\\u003b'
    COLLECTION ITEMS TERMINATED BY '\\u003b'
    MAP KEYS TERMINATED BY '|'
STORED AS TEXTFILE;

LOAD DATA LOCAL INPATH '...' INTO TABLE string_array;
```

Any ideas how to make it work so I can build upon it? Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Great question.

I think that we can break this problem up into two discrete pieces: (1) Hive table structure, and (2) data delimiters.

Let's start by looking at the Hive table structure.  If I understood your data structure correctly (please correct me if I didn't), the table structure that would best describe your data could be represented as:

```
CREATE TABLE string_array
AS
SELECT 'fieldA,fieldB,fieldC' AS first_part, array(map('fieldD', array('fieldE', 'FieldF')), map('fieldG', array('fieldH','FieldI'))) AS second_part;
```

Note that the field second_part is an array of maps, where the key to each map references an array of strings.  In other words, the field second_part consists of an array within a map within an array.

If I use the statement above to create a table, I can then copy the resulting table to the local filesystem and look at how Hive assigns default delimiters to it.  I know that you don't want to use default delimiters, but please bear with me here.  The resulting table looks like this in its serialized on-disk representation:

```
00000000  66 69 65 6c 64 41 2c 66  69 65 6c 64 42 2c 66 69  |fieldA,fieldB,fi|
00000010  65 6c 64 43 01 66 69 65  6c 64 44 04 66 69 65 6c  |eldC.fieldD.fiel|
00000020  64 45 05 46 69 65 6c 64  46 02 66 69 65 6c 64 47  |dE.FieldF.fieldG|
00000030  04 66 69 65 6c 64 48 05  46 69 65 6c 64 49 0a     |.fieldH.FieldI.|
```

If we look at how ***Hive*** sees the delimiters we note that Hive actually sees five types or levels of delimiters:

```
delimiter 1 = x'01' (between fieldC & fieldD) -- between first_part and second_part
delimiter 2 = x'02' (between fieldF & fieldG) -- between the two maps in the array of maps
delimiter 3 = x'03' not used
delimiter 4 = x'04' (between fieldD & fieldE) -- between the key and the array of fields within the map
delimiter 5 = x'05' (between fieldE & fieldF) -- between the fields within the array within the map
```

And herein lies your problem.  Current versions of Hive ([as of 0.11.0](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-3682)) only allow you to override three levels of delimiters.  But due to the levels of nesting within your data, Hive is seeing a requirement for greater than three levels of delimiters.

My suggestion would be to pre-process your data to use Hive's default delimiters.  With this approach you should be able to load your data into Hive and reference it.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I was hoping to import the data s is since the preprocessing will take lots of time. But if its unavoidable, it has to be done ...